# Unable to adjust Brightness in Hp probook 4430s

Tags: windows-7-x64, monitor, screen-brightness

I recently installed Windows 7 professional for my laptop and I am unable to adjust its brightness when I using fn+brightness(low or high) button , I see the symbol but it does not change.

I have tried other methods but they have not seem to work for me.

[image: Below Image shows when I pressed the fn+ brightness(high) button symbol came but brightness did not change on repetitive press for brightness while holding the fn keys.]

Thanks,
Akshay

Answer (score -1):

I found out the solution myself , the brightness of the screen is associated with the graphics card of the system.

So all we have to do is following -
1. Open device management by typing device manager in the search of windows.
2. Then go to display adapter tab.
3. Open the display adapter tab there u will be seeing a yellow diamond like sign,        now right click on it and click on update driver software , choose search for the driver online option and click next , and that it.
4. Restart your pc , U will now be able to adjust the brightness.

Thanks..